# A prime number simplex

Tags: prime-number-theorem

Let $\ n\in\mathbf N:= \{1\ 2\ \ldots\}\ $ be a natural number.

Let $\ K\ $ be a non-empty finite set of primes. Let $\ \kappa:=|K|.\ $ Consider a $\kappa$-dimensional simplex $\ S_K\subseteq \mathbf R^K\ $ which has the origin as one of its vertices, and the vertex along the $p$-axis at $\ \frac{log(n)}{\log(p)}.\ $ The volume of $\ S_k\ $ is:

$$ V_K\ :=\ \frac{(\log(n))^\kappa}{\kappa!\cdot\prod_{p\in K}\log(p)} $$

Now let $\ K\ $ be the set of all primes which do not exceed $\ n.\ $ Then the volume $\ V_K\ $ may be naively viewed as a crude approximation on $\ n.\ $ Thus, what is the true relation between $\ n\ $ and $\ V_K\,$?

Comment: Why does it approximate $n$? It tends to zero, since $\kappa!$ is huge compared even to $(\log n)^{\kappa}$.

Comment: You are right. I guess, the simplex is too thin to have volume anywhere near the number of the integer points of the simplex under the consideration, where the number of these points is $n$ indeed. (Hm, I knew this kind of behavior even from studying some applications. Thank you for your answers. Thus, how do we take advantage of this geometry without the notion of volume used in a too straight way?

Comment: By the way, the @FedorPetrov 's observation about limit being $0$ is a consequence of a theorem which is harder than Euclid or Fermat numbers $\ 2^{2^n}-1\ $ level about the prime infinitude.